# Why is this query so slow compared to Python code?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I have an SQLite database with multiple tables. Two of these tables are `users` and `posts` created using the following statements in Python:

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
             (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              user_name TEXT,
              num_posts_parsed INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              num_posts_userpage INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              num_received_likes INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              num_points INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              banned INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              deleted INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              join_date TEXT)''')

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts
             (post_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              thread_id INTEGER,
              author_id INTEGER,
              post_number INTEGER,
              creation_date TEXT,
              post_text TEXT,
              post_link TEXT,
              number_chars INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              number_words INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              number_smilies INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              number_likes INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              number_edits INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
              FOREIGN KEY (thread_id) REFERENCES threads(thread_id),
              FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users(user_id))''')
```

`posts` table has 2.1 million rows and `user` table contains about 10k entries. I want an SQL statement that:

1. Obtains all posts created after 2019-04-01 and contain at least one word.
2. For each author that created one of these posts, counts how many likes (column `number_likes`) per post were received.
3. But only includes those authors who have written at least 100 posts since 2019-04-01.
4. Retrieves top n authors (user names) with the highest like per post ratio.

I came up with:

```
query = '''SELECT users.user_name, CAST(SUM(posts.number_likes) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(posts.post_id) as ratio
            FROM users 
            JOIN (
                SELECT *
                FROM posts
                WHERE number_words > 0 AND creation_date >= '2019-04-01'
            ) AS posts ON users.user_id = posts.author_id
            WHERE users.user_id IN (
                SELECT author_id
                FROM posts
                WHERE creation_date >= '2019-04-01'
                GROUP BY author_id
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 100
            )
            GROUP BY users.user_name
            HAVING SUM(posts.number_likes) > 0
            ORDER BY ratio DESC
            LIMIT ?'''
```

This is terribly slow. I stopped it after several hours. Instead, I wrote a Python function:

```
def get_users_likes_per_post_after_like_introduction(db, n):
    query = '''SELECT author_id, number_likes
                FROM posts 
                JOIN users ON users.user_id = posts.author_id
                WHERE number_words > 0 AND creation_date >= '2019-04-01'
                '''
    db.cursor.execute(query)
    authors_likes = db.cursor.fetchall()
    res = {}
    for (author_id, likes) in authors_likes:
        if author_id in res:
            res[author_id][0] += 1
            res[author_id][1] += likes
        else:
            res[author_id] = [1, likes]
    likes_per_post = [(author_id, likes / num_posts) for author_id, (num_posts, likes) in res.items() if
                      num_posts >= 100]
    likes_per_post_sorted = sorted(likes_per_post, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    relevant_part = likes_per_post_sorted[:n]
    user_ids = [x[0] for x in relevant_part]
    like_ratio = [x[1] for x in relevant_part]

    user_names = []
    for uid in user_ids:
        query = f"SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id  = {uid}"
        user_names.append(db.cursor.execute(query).fetchone()[0])

    return [(name, like_ratio) for name, like_ratio in zip(user_names, like_ratio)]
```

This finishes after seconds. There may be ways to clean up this function and make it even faster, but that is not the point. Why is the SQL statement so slow? How would an SQL statement look that is of similar speed as my Python code? There are no indexes in the database.

Comment: you have no indexes on the tables, so searching for elements by creation date requires searching the entire table.

Comment: A big part of debugging db SQL performance is using `EXPLAIN` to see what the execution plan is and where it's spending its time, revealing the bottleneck. Please include its output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE ... IN` clause is suspicious (that could be a huge list of `IN` items).

This version may give you the same results but I'm hedging my bets without some test data to go on:

```
SELECT 
    X.user_name,
    CAST(x.number_likes as FLOAT) / X.count_posts as ratio
FROM
(
SELECT 
    users.user_name, 
    SUM(posts.number_likes) As sum_likes,
    COUNT(posts.post_id) as count_posts
    FROM 
        users 
        JOIN posts
        ON users.user_id = posts.author_id
    WHERE 
        number_words > 0 
        AND number_likes > 0
        AND creation_date >= '2019-04-01'
    GROUP BY author_id
) X
WHERE X.count_posts >= 100;
```

For a table with millions of records - do consider if you have set up primary keys and indexes appropriately).